google sheets token for pressac gateway connections
trying to connect google cloud (sheets) with pressac gateway
Hello - trying to connect google cloud (sheets) with pressac gateway following this step by step but the mesage I receive is invalid token. is there anyway you could help? Thanks
https://support.pressac.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-the-google-sheets-connection-on-your-gateway
